# Same WCF binding configuration but error only on one

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, wcf-endpoint

So I have a WCF service with 2 ServiceContracts + MEX. So that's 3 endpoints.

Two of the endpoints that connect to each service contract use a `netTcpBinding` and utilize the same `bindingConfiguration`.

From one spot I have to use both services. The config on the client side is identical but I get a exception on one off the proxies call (`contractFilter mismatch`) but not the other. How can that be. If bot configurations are the same and both configs as well how can one work but not the other.

Note that the problem service is a Duplex type.

Here are the two service contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, Name = "VpUser")]
public interface IVpClientService

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, Name = "VpAdmin", CallbackContract = typeof(IAdminCallback))] 
public interface IVpAdminService

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public partial class VpService : IVpClientService, IVpAdminService, IServiceBehavior
```

The web.config on the service side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Off">
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="false"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
        <endToEndTracing messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="VpNetTcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="true"  closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:22:00" sendTimeout="00:24:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="131072" >
                <reliableSession enabled="false" inactivityTimeout="00:50:00"/>
                <security mode="Transport"  >
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
        <mexHttpBinding>
            <binding name="mexHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:02:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" />
        </mexHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="VpServiceBehavior" name="VP.VpService.VpService">
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding"
          name="MexMetadata" contract="IMetadataExchange" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
            <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VpNetTcpBinding"
          name="HttpClient" contract="VP.VpService.IVpClientService">
                <identity>
                    <dns />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VpNetTcpBinding"
          name="HttpAdminClient" contract="VP.VpService.IVpAdminService">
                <identity>
                    <dns />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="VpServiceBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceThrottling
            maxConcurrentCalls="32"
            maxConcurrentSessions="100"
            maxConcurrentInstances="132"
            />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

and the config on the client side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="HttpClient" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:06:00" sendTimeout="00:06:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:01:00"
              enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="HttpAdminClient" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
            receiveTimeout="00:06:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
            transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:01:00"
                           enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://MyDomain:443/SubDomain/vpservice.svc"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpClient"
            contract="VPService.VpUser" name="HttpClient">
            <identity>
                <dns />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://MyDomain:443/SubDomain//vpservice.svc"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpAdminClient"
          contract="VPService.VpAdmin" name="HttpAdminClient">
            <identity>
                <dns />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Notice that the HTTP name prefix is a legacy since before it was changed to netTcp.

So I can build the proxies and `open()` but as soon as I make a few Async call (one to the Admin client and two to the other one) I get a Contract Mismathc fault on the admin but the other two run succesfully.

How can that be?

Comment: [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) equals No Configuration files, the bane of WCF.  ServiceStack is the way to go.  Just looking at your config above is a nightmare, don't you agree?

Comment: @ChuckSavage Yes I agree, but mostly it's a pain to debug what the problem is and it always seems to be some config problem but never apparent what it is. Sadly I didn't design the service and won't be modifying it. However I might read more about `ServiceStack` in the future, thank you.

Comment: You can use ServiceStack to connect to existing WCF services.